# Find the required permissions of Django URLs without calling them?

Tags: django, menu, authorization

My Django app currently has URLs which are protected by 'permission_required()' functions.

This function is called in three different ways.

1. As a decorator in views.py, with hardcoded parameters.
2. As a plain function, with autogenerated parameter, in custom Class Based Generic Views.
3. As a function invoking views in urls.py, with hardcoded parameters.

I'm now adding a menu system to the app, and I need to make menu entries reflect whether the user has permission to request the URL of each menu entry.  (Either by greying-out or hiding said entries.)

Is there a way of query the permissions required to a URL *without* requesting the URL?

The only solution I've thought of so far is to replace the decorator with a parameterless 'menu_permssion_required()' decorator and hardcode all of the permissions into a Python structure.  This seems like a step backwards, as my custom Class Based Generic Views already autogenerate their required permissions.

Any suggestions on how to make a menu system which reflects URL permissions for the current user?

Comment: I always hardcode menus in templates, it's simple and allows contextual menus with {% extends %}.

Comment: @jplc apologies, I can't understand the how your comment relates to the question.  This is specifically about permissions.  Permissions are cross-cutting, not linked to URL prefix or similar.

Comment: You can check for permissions in the template: https://gist.github.com/25c03f286337c66cc860 This is pretty standard in django projects from what I've seen, here's the docs about the django perms module in question: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.0/topics/auth/#id6 Still, my point is that time spent making a "system" for an HTML menu might be better spent on other things.

Comment: @jpic thanks for the clarification.  My objective is to avoid the duplication of specifying permissions in *both* the menu template *and* other places.  If I don't, they *will* get out of sync at some point, and customers will be unnecessarily shown error pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of how to solve your problem:

First, Create a decorator wrapper to use instead of permission_required:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required, permission_required, user_passes_test
from django.core.exceptions import PermissionDenied
from functools import wraps
from  django.utils.decorators import available_attrs

def require_perms(*perms):
    def decorator(view_func):
        view_func.permissions = perms
        @wraps(view_func, assigned=available_attrs(view_func))
        def _wrapped_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
            for perm in perms:
                return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
            raise PermissionDenied()
        return _wrapped_view
    return decorator
```

Then, use it to decorate your views:

```
@require_perms('my_perm',)
def home(request):
.....
```

Then, add a tag to use for your menu items:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import resolve

def check_menu_permissions(menu_path, user):
    view = resolve(menu_path)
    if hasattr(view.func, "permissions"):
        permissions = view.func.permissions
        for perm in permissions:
            if user.has_perm(perm):
                return True # Yep, the user can access this url
            else:
                return False # Nope, the user cannot access this url
    return True #  or False - depending on what is the default behavior
```

And finally, in your templates, when building the menu tree:

```
<button href="{{ some_path }} {% if not check_menu_permissions some_path request.user %}disabled="disabled"{% endif %} />
```

N.B. I've not tested the last part with the tag, but I hope you got the idea. The magic thing here is to add the permissions to the view_func in the decorator, and then you can access this using resolve(path). I'm not sure how this will behave in terms of performance, but after all that's just an idea.

**EDIT**: Just fixed a bug in the example..

Comment: Thanks, I love the general idea.  I'll let you know how it works in practice before the end of the month (project deadline).

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way of query the permissions required to a URL without requesting the URL?

[User.has_perm()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.0/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.has_perm) and [User.has_module_perms()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.0/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.has_module_perms)

> Any suggestions on how to make a menu system which reflects URL permissions for the current user?

I really like this question, because it concerns anyone that makes a website with django, so I find it really relevant. I've been through that myself and even [coded a menu "system"](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1091/) in my first django project back in 2008. But since then I tried Pinax, and one of the (so many) things I learnt from their example projects is that it is completely unnecessary bloat.

So, I have no suggestion which I would support on how to make a menu "system" which respects the request user permissions.

I do have a suggestion on how to make a simple menu which respects the request user permissions, so that might not be completely unrelated.

1. **Just make your menu in plain HTML**, it's not like it's going to change so often that it has to be generated. That will also keep your Python code simpler.
2. Add to `settings.TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`: `'django.core.context_processors.PermWrapper'`
3. Use the [`{{ perms }} proxy`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.0/topics/auth/#id6) to User.has_perms.

Example:

```
{% if perms.auth %}
    <li class="divider"></li>

    {% if perms.auth.change_user %} 
    <li>
        <a href="{% url admin:auth_user_changelist %}">{% trans 'Users' %}</a>
    </li>
    {% endif %} 

    {% if perms.auth.change_group %} 
    <li>
        <a href="{% url admin:auth_group_changelist %}">{% trans 'User groups' %}</a>
    </li>
    {% endif %} 

{% endif %} 
{# etc, etc #}
```

That's how I keep navigation **simple**, **stupid**, and **out of the way**. But also I always include [an autocomplete](http://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.org/en/latest/navigation.html) not far from the menus to allows the user to navigate to any detail page easily. So, that's all I know about navigation in django projects, I'm eager to read other answers !

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, but it went a little deeper. Instead of just permissions, I also wanted other tests based on the lidded in user (ie, `is_staff`, or `user.units.count() > 1`). Duplicating these in the view and the template seems prone to errors.

You can introspect a view object, and see all of the decorators wrapping it, and work out if they are checks (in my case: the first argument I'd `u` or `user`). If they all pass, then allow rendering the link.

[Get all decorators wrapping a function](http://schinckel.net/2012/01/20/get-decorators-wrapping-a-function/) describes the technique in a little more detail. You can find the app that wraps this up into a handy replacement for `{% url %}` at [Django-menus](http://Bitbucket.org/schinckel/django-menus).

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at Django-menus and see if it does what I require.  If I end up having to code this myself (as I use my own custom persmissions decorator), I will go with Tisho's answer, as it is significantly less 'magical'.