# In Django template: Check if user has permission to access view specified by name

Tags: django, django-templates, django-authentication

Say I have a view that has been decorated with the `user_passes_test` decorator:

```
# myapp/views.py
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test

def has_perm1_or_perm2(user):
    return user.has_perm('myapp.perm1') or user.has_perm('myapp.perm2')

@user_passes_test(has_perm1_or_perm2)
class MyView(TemplateView):
    # my view code goes here
```

and I hook it up to a URL as follows:

```
# myapp/urls.py
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    ...,
    url(r'^myview$', views.MyView.as_view(), name='myview'),
    ...
]
```

If I wanted to put a link to this view in a template, it would look something like:

```
<a href="{% url 'myapp:myview' %}">Check out my view!</a>
```

But I would like to be able to put some control into the template so that the above is only shown if the currently-logged-in user would be approved by the `user_passes_test` function specified for the view.

I.e. I'd like to have my template look something like:

```
{% if check_user_has_view_permission request.user 'myapp:myview' %}
<a href="{% url 'myapp:myview' %}">Check out my view!</a>
{% else %}
Nothing to see here...
{% endif %}
```

How can I make that happen?

Thanks!

Comment: Note that the `user_passes_test` decorator is for procedural views. For class-based views you need to use [a mixin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.UserPassesTestMixin).

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to comment.  I had thought that in the past, it was possible to decorate class-based views.  Is this a new thing in 1.9 that you need to use mixins for CBV's?  Or is it only permission-related decorators on CBV's?  Or is this just recommended, but the decorator approach will still work?

Comment: Decorators will not work AFAIK. Before Django 1.9 you had to write your own mixins or decorate the `dispatch` method of the view.

Comment: I thought the docs indicated the class-decorating approach worked (as long as you wrapped your decorator inside the `method_decorator` function): https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-the-class

Comment: From the link you referenced: "To decorate every instance of a class-based view, you need to decorate the class definition itself. **To do this you apply the decorator to the `dispatch()` method of the class.**"

Comment: Or about 2 paragraphs lower on the same page: **Or, more succinctly, you can decorate the class instead and pass the name of the method to be decorated as the keyword argument name:**

Comment: Yes, you are right! However you then use the `method_decorator` function and pass a `name` argument. i.e., you cannot directly decorate the class with `user_passes_test`.

Answer (score 2):

You can write a [custom template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-template-tags/) that will do this:

```
# myapp/templatetags/my_app_tags.py (probably need a better name...)
from django import template
from myapp.views import has_perm1_or_perm2

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
user_has_special_perms(user):
    return has_perm1_or_perm2(user)
```

Then in your template:

```
{% load my_app_tags %}

{% if request.user|user_has_special_perms %}
<a href="{% url 'myapp:myview' %}">Check out my view!</a>
{% else %}
Nothing to see here...
{% endif %}
```

Alternatively you can check the individual permissions directly like so:

```
{% if perms.myapp.perm1 and perms.myapp.perm2 %}
```

(obviously this is less DRY).

**EDIT - how can this be made more generic?**

To make this more generic, you could do something like this. First create some sort of mapping of views to permissions, e.g.,:

```
# myapp/views.py
VIEW_PERMISSIONS = {
    'MyView': has_perm1_or_perm2,
    # etc for other views
}
```

Then modify the template filter like so:

```
from myapp.views import VIEW_PERMISSIONS

@register.filter
user_has_special_perms(user, view_class):
    perm_func = VIEW_PERMISSIONS.get(view_class, None)
    if perm_func is not None:
        return perm_func(user)
    return false
```

And then in the template:

```
{% if request.user|user_has_special_perms:"MyView" %}
```

I'm sure it is possible to achieve this without requiring an explicit mapping through `VIEW_PERMISSIONS`, using some kind of introspection on the view class itself.

Comment: This is a reasonable start, but it's not as general as I'd like in its current presentation.  In particular, in my real application, I'll have dozens of view functions, each of which will have a (potentially) bespoke user authorization checking function.  (View 1 might be `perma or permb`...view 2 might be `perma and permc`, etc.)  So it's essential that the solution not require the manual step of generating a filter for each user-permission-checking function...the tag needs to automatically figure out what function applies to a given view based on its URL name.  Possible?

Comment: I have edited to answer to give one possible approach to making it more generic. Ideally you need to do some introspection on the class itself.

Comment: I'm reading this answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10966493/find-the-required-permissions-of-django-urls-without-calling-them) in detail to see if I can leverage that approach.  In particular, it looks like the author there suggests a suped-up version of the core permission-checking decorator.  In particular, before the decorating occurs, it attaches the validation function itself as an attribute on the view function.  That should make it possible to recall the validation function later on.